# Git Diff get list of only INI files - Windows 7

Tags: windows, git, cmd, git-diff

This is how I used it when I was on Mac.

```
git diff refs/tags/l-build..HEAD --name-only $(find . -name *\.ini)  >> log.txt
```

But I am moving back to Windows. And I get this error using git-bash

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '$(find': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

i think there would be no problems with Windows Bash on Windows 10 but I have to use Windows 7 because of limitations of some important software I have to use daily in my work.

Comment: Have you tried `git diff refs/tags/l-build..HEAD -- *.ini  >> log.txt`?

Comment: GfW bundle has ports of certain Unix tools inside. The GfW installer proposes you to make them available to your normal shell (by listing them in the system `PATH` env. var.), so you might consider reinstalling GfW and enabling that option — this might bring more familiar unix-y tools at your disposal.

Comment: @Jubobs that does not work.

Comment: @kostix that is to complicated just to solve one command.

Comment: (shrugs) I, for one, cannot live without `grep`, `find` and the tools of its ilk, so I either abuse what ships with GfW or use packages from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ (which is sadly abandoned by the last time I needed to do serious stuff on Windows, they worked for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command to filter out `.ini` files first then apply the `git diff` command.

```
git ls-files -m | grep '.ini'
```

Combinedly, as below :

```
git diff `git ls-files -m | grep .ini`
```

Comment: No need to add `grep` in the mix (and the OP's machine most probably does not have one, too): `git ls-files *.ini` should work just fine.